# cakephp + ckeditor....how to bind keyup event

Tags: cakephp, ckeditor, cakephp-2.0

i want to store data in ckeditor instantly to a file using ajax. I am using cakephp and i have following code in my view file to test whether ckeditor is successfully bound to js event.

```
    <?php
echo $this->Html->script('ckeditor/ckeditor');
echo $this->Form->create('Post', array('action' => 'edit'));
echo $this->Form->input('title',array('id'=>'posttitle'));
echo $this->Form->input('id', array('value'=>$originalid,'type' => 'hidden'));
echo $this->Form->input('username', array('value'=>$creator,'type' => 'hidden'));
echo $this->Form->textarea('body',array('class'=>'ckeditor','id'=>'postbody'));
echo $this->Form->end('Done Editing');

$this->Js->get('#postbody');
echo $this->Js->event('click','alert("hi")');
    ?>
```

the problem is that the code works fine when I bind it with input of title but it doesn't work with textarea containing ckeditor.

Comment: It might be because ckeditor modifies or generates a another textarea (if its not other thing) in live time. What does it show Chrome or Firefox DOM inspector where the textarea is suppose to be?

Comment: ya, lookup what the html looks like, ckeditor does replace the textarea with its own id.

Comment: thanx for the comment..i think the problem is that instead of putting a simple textarea. there is an iframe that replaces the textarea and no keyup event is able to bind to it.

Comment: Could you not use native JS for this?

Comment: i did..that is unable to get me textarea too..:(

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused partly because of the CakePHP JS stuff. What are you trying to achieve with the keyup event? Do you want to save always when any changes happen or do you want to update the textarea content every time the editor changes or...? There are better ways to do both in my opinion than this but what to do depends a lot on what you are wanting to achieve (some changes can happen without keyup events, think undo/redo/bold/add table for example).

In CKE you don't attach the events to the underlying element but rather it has it's own event model that is quite handy. In native JS you would listen to the key event like so:

```
editor.on('key', function(e)
{
    console.log("Ponies");
});
```

There `editor` would be your ckeditor instance. It's very similar for click events.